# Can I show that the limit of the square root is the square root of the limit this way?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given, for all natural k and a convergence sequence $a_n$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((a_n)^k\right)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)^k
$$

I have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{n}}=1$. So:
$$
(a_n)^2 = 1-\frac{2}{n}=> \lim_{n\to\infty}\left((a_n)^2\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)=1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{n}}
$$

Can I do this? thank you.

Comment: You mentioned you don't have continuity yet - do you have the squeeze (or sandwich) theorem?

Comment: yes. I have tried that but couldn't find 2 sequences. I have found only a greater one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use that method directly, because you haven't yet shown that $a_n$ converges. Fortunately, you can say first that $a_n < 1$ for all $n$, and it is an increasing sequence, so must converge. Then, your argument works.

Alternatively (in my opinion the more natural approach), observe that $1 - \frac{2}{n} < \sqrt{1 - \frac{2}{n}}< 1$, so we have convergence by the squeeze theorem.

Specifically, 
$$\begin{align} \sqrt{1 - \frac{2}{n}} < 1 \implies \sqrt{1 - \frac{2}{n}}\times \sqrt{1 - \frac{2}{n}} < \sqrt{1 - \frac{2}{n}} \implies 1 - \frac{2}{n} < \sqrt{1 - \frac{2}{n}}\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you observe that 1-2/n is less or equals to...?

Comment: @MorHaham I have added more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Note that,
if $0 < x < 1$,
then
$(1-x)^2 = 1-2x+x^2
=1-x-x+x^2
=1-x-x(1-x)
\lt 1-x
$,
so,
taking square roots,
$1-x < \sqrt{1-x}
$.

This lets you squeeze.

If you want an upper bound,
$(1-x/2)^2
=1-x+x^2
\gt 1-x
$
so
$1-x/2 > \sqrt{1-x}$.

Therefore,
if $0 < x < 1$,
$1-x < \sqrt{1-x}
\lt 1-x/2$.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried for hours to find an appropriate sequence to squeeze and didn't think about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If worse comes to worse we can do it directly.

For $\epsilon > 0$ we want to show there is an $N_\epsilon$ so that whenever $n > N_\epsilon$ we have $|\sqrt{(1 - \frac 2n)} - 1|< \epsilon$.

Let's work backwards.

For $2< n$ then $\frac 2n > 0$ so $1-\frac 2n < 1$ so $\sqrt{(1-\frac 2n)} < 1$ so $|\sqrt{1-\frac 2n)} -1| = 1- \sqrt{1-\frac 2n} < \epsilon \Leftarrow$ ("is implied by"; we are working *backwards*).

$1-\epsilon < \sqrt{1-\frac 2n}\Leftarrow$

$(1-\epsilon)^2 = 1- 2\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < 1-\frac 2n$

As we may assume $\epsilon < 1$ so $-2\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < -2\epsilon + \epsilon = - \epsilon$$

$\Leftarrow 1- \epsilon < (1-\epsilon)^2 < 1 - \frac 2n \Leftarrow$

$\frac 2n < \epsilon; \epsilon < 1\Leftarrow$

$\frac 2\epsilon < n$ so let $N = \frac 2\epsilon$ and... we are done.

....

Of course, no one *likes* to do that and we invented squeeze theorems and analysis of continuous functions, etc. just so that we don't *HAVE* to keep doing this stuff.

But... If worse comes worse, we always *can*.